# Separador ; con fputcsv y forzar encerrar cada campo de texto entre comillas

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

¿Cómo se escribe en un CSV con `fputcsv` los campos de texto entre comillas y separados por `;`?

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php
  $archivo = "testFile.csv";
         $separador=';';
         $enclosure='"';
         $gestor = fopen ($archivo, 'w');
         $alumnos=$_SESSION['alumnos'];

            foreach ($alumnos as $alumno) {
                fputcsv ($gestor,$alumno,$separador,$enclosure);
            foreach ($alumno as $notas) {
              fputcsv($gestor,$notas);
            }
            }
            fclose ($gestor);
        fclose($f);
```

Y la salida que me genera es:

```
Eugenio,Martinez,45,Array  
Marta,Carrera,22,Array  
Nacho,Herrera,25,Array
```

Y quería que fuese algo como:

```
"Eugenio";"Martinez";45;"1,2,4,5"  
"Fran";"Gonzlez";31;"6,4.9,5,8"  
"Marta";"Rodriguez";22;"3.2,9,10"
```

La salida que me genera `var_dump($alumnos)` es ésta:

```
array(5) { 
   [0]=> array(4) { 
         ["nombre"]=> string(7) "Eugenio" 
         ["apellido"]=> string(8) "Martinez" 
         ["edad"]=> int(45) 
         ["notas"]=> array(3) { 
                    [0]=> int(7) 
                    [1]=> int(6) 
                    [2]=> int(5) 
        }
   } 
   [1]=> array(4) { 
         ["nombre"]=> string(5) "Marta" 
         ["apellido"]=> string(7) "Carrera" 
         ["edad"]=> int(22) 
         ["notas"]=> array(3) { 
                    [0]=> int(1) 
                    [1]=> int(6) 
                    [2]=> int(2) 
         } 
    } 
    [2]=> array(4) { 
         ["nombre"]=> string(5) "Nacho"  
         ["apellido"]=> string(7) "Herrera" 
         ["edad"]=> int(25) 
         ["notas"]=> array(3) { 
                    [0]=> int(3) 
                    [1]=> int(4) 
                    [2]=> int(2) 
         } 
     }
}
```

Ésta es la salida que genera `var_export($alumnos)`:

```
array ( 
0 => array ( 'nombre' => 'Eugenio', 'apellido' => 'Martinez', 'edad' => 45, 'notas' => array ( 0 => 7, 1 => 6, 2 => 5, ), ), 
1 => array ( 'nombre' => 'Marta', 'apellido' => 'Carrera', 'edad' => 22, 'notas' => array ( 0 => 1, 1 => 6, 2 => 2, ), ), 
2 => array ( 'nombre' => 'Nacho', 'apellido' => 'Herrera', 'edad' => 25, 'notas' => array ( 0 => 3, 1 => 4, 2 => 2, ), ), 
)
```

Comment: logro separar con ; pero no que cada campo me lo indique entre comillas.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: el tercer parámetro `';'` y el cuarto parámetro `'"'`

Comment: no consigo que el cuarto parametro me coloque las comillas.  fputcsv ($gestor,$alumno,$separador,$enclosure);

Comment: pero o esta mal planteada tu pregunta o no has colocado lo ultimo que intentaste, agregando la parte del `enclosure`

Comment: tienes razon, edito la pregunta gracias

Comment: Dos cosas: muéstranos  `var_dump($alumnos)` y no puedes poner dos llamadas a `fputcsv()`  con datos diferentes, lo que debes hacer es dejar solo el del `foreach` más interno y ahí concatenar (con array_merge por ejemplo) todos los campos. Tal como lo muestras cada `fputcsv()` generará filas con diferentes contenidos.

Comment: Procura usar `var_export()` en vez de `var_dump()`. Genera una salida que podemos asignar directamente una variable para reproducir tu problema y poder ayudarte. Gracias.

Comment: He podido reproducir tu problema, pero veo que las comillas no las pone si no hay espacios en blanco en la cadena de caracteres.

Comment: PHP Version 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 segun lo que me aparece con `phpinfo()`

Comment: Según veo en el [código de PHP](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/db0079023421b8048f090ee04adb992e09132553/ext/standard/file.c#L1872) no es posible forzar el entrecomillado usando esa función :( Exactamente [en esta línea de código](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/db0079023421b8048f090ee04adb992e09132553/ext/standard/file.c#L1885) se decide entrecomillar únicamente los datos que contengan un delimitador, un carácter de cierre, una nueva línea o un espacio en blanco (`FPUTCSV_FLD_CHK(' ')`). ¿Usas `composer`? ¿Has probado alternativas como https://github.com/thephpleague/csv ?

Comment: Ok. muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo y toda la ayuda! ahora a seguir probando.

Comment: @cisco , no puedo abrir un chat para hablar contigo de este tema porque aún no tienes suficiente reputación :( ¿qué solución admitirías? ¿saber por qué no se generan las comillas o buscar una solución para forzarlas?

Comment: @OscarGarcia realmente admitiria cualquiera y ambas, voy a seguir probando y a ver si logro forzarlas de algun modo, pero tambien leer para documentarme mas sobre estas funciones ya que estoy comenzando con php y toda ayuda y lectura es poca xd

Comment: Hola @cisco , he redactado una respuesta explicando paso a paso cómo "engañar" a PHP para que fuerce la generación de las comillas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por desgracia la [función de generación de CSV `fputcsv()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/db0079023421b8048f090ee04adb992e09132553/ext/standard/file.c#L1872) de la que dispone PHP no permite personalizar la salida tanto como deseáramos y, [como puede verse en el código fuente](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/db0079023421b8048f090ee04adb992e09132553/ext/standard/file.c#L1885), sólo fuerza las comillas en las cadenas que contengan un delimitador, retorno del carro, tabulador, espacio en blanco, etc.

Para engañar a PHP y forzar la generación del entrecomillado [podemos usar un truco](https://github.com/thephpleague/csv/blob/853a121cc3efea30499d9a3ce17382e882da6782/src/EncloseField.php#L133) que he visto usar en [`thephpleague/csv`](https://github.com/thephpleague/csv) que consiste en agregar una cadena (que raramente pueda producirse en condiciones normales) que contenga algún carácter que fuerce la generación de las comillas y posteriormente eliminar dicha cadena del resultado haciendo uso de un [filtro en la corriente de datos](http://php.net/es/stream-filter-register).

Para ello primero deberemos crear una clase que extienda de [`php_user_filter`](http://php.net/es/php_user_filter) que implemente la eliminación de la cadena que realiza el "truco":

```
/* Esta es una cadena difícilmente reproducible en condiciones normales */
define('TRUCO_CSV', "\t\x1f");
/* Esta clase será la encargada de filtrar lo que se mande al archivo */
class filtrar_csv extends php_user_filter {
  function filter($in, $out, &$consumed, $closing)
  {
    /* Por cada trozo de datos, aplicamos eliminamos la cadena "truco" */
    while ($bucket = stream_bucket_make_writeable($in)) {
      $bucket->data = str_replace(TRUCO_CSV, '', $bucket->data);
      $consumed += $bucket->datalen;
      stream_bucket_append($out, $bucket);
    }
    /* Salida sin error */
    return PSFS_PASS_ON;
  }
}
```

Luego deberemos registrar el filtro con un nombre (en nuestro ejemplo tiene el mismo nombre que la clase creada) y la aplicamos a la corriente de datos abierta con `fopen()`:

```
/* Registramos el filtro y lo agregamos al archivo */
stream_filter_register("filtrar_csv", "filtrar_csv");
stream_filter_append($gestor, "filtrar_csv", STREAM_FILTER_WRITE);
```

Por último deberemos asegurarnos que todos los campos que queramos forzar su entrecomillado contengan la cadena "trampa". En nuestro caso lo únicamente las cadenas de texto y con el resultado de unir las notas por comas:

```
  /* Por cada elemento de los datos analizamos su contenido */
  foreach($alumno as $campo => $valor) {
    switch(gettype($valor)) {
      /* Si es una cadena forzaremos las comillas agregando el "truco" */
      case 'string':
        $alumno[$campo] .= TRUCO_CSV;
        break;
      /* Si es una matriz unimos sus datos con una coma y forzamos las comillas también */
      case 'array':
        $alumno[$campo] = implode(',', $alumno[$campo]) . TRUCO_CSV;
        break;
    }
  }
```

---

El script PHP completo que reproduce los resultados es:

```
<?php
$alumnos = array (
  0 =>
  array (
    'nombre' => 'Eugenio',
    'apellido' => 'Martinez',
    'edad' => 45,
    'notas' =>
    array (
      0 => 7,
      1 => 6,
      2 => 5,
    ),
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    'nombre' => 'Marta',
    'apellido' => 'Carrera',
    'edad' => 22,
    'notas' =>
    array (
      0 => 1,
      1 => 6,
      2 => 2,
    ),
  ),
  2 =>
  array (
    'nombre' => 'Nacho',
    'apellido' => 'Herrera',
    'edad' => 25,
    'notas' =>
    array (
      0 => 3,
      1 => 4,
      2 => 2,
    ),
  ),
);

$separador=';';
$enclosure='"';

/* Esta es una cadena difícilmente reproducible en condiciones normales */
define('TRUCO_CSV', "\t\x1f");

/* Abrimos el archivo, en mi caso la salida en pantalla */
$gestor = fopen ('php://stdout', 'w');

/* Esta clase será la encargada de filtrar lo que se mande al archivo */
class filtrar_csv extends php_user_filter {
  function filter($in, $out, &$consumed, $closing)
  {
    /* Por cada trozo de datos, aplicamos eliminamos la cadena "truco" */
    while ($bucket = stream_bucket_make_writeable($in)) {
      $bucket->data = str_replace(TRUCO_CSV, '', $bucket->data);
      $consumed += $bucket->datalen;
      stream_bucket_append($out, $bucket);
    }
    /* Salida sin error */
    return PSFS_PASS_ON;
  }
}
/* Registramos el filtro y lo agregamos al archivo */
stream_filter_register("filtrar_csv", "filtrar_csv");
stream_filter_append($gestor, "filtrar_csv", STREAM_FILTER_WRITE);

foreach ($alumnos as $alumno) {
  /* Por cada elemento de los datos analizamos su contenido */
  foreach($alumno as $campo => $valor) {
    switch(gettype($valor)) {
      /* Si es una cadena forzaremos las comillas agregando el "truco" */
      case 'string':
        $alumno[$campo] .= TRUCO_CSV;
        break;
      /* Si es una matriz unimos sus datos con una coma y forzamos las comillas también */
      case 'array':
        $alumno[$campo] = implode(',', $alumno[$campo]) . TRUCO_CSV;
        break;
    }
  }
  fputcsv($gestor, $alumno, $separador, $enclosure);
}
fclose($gestor);
```

La salida generada será:

```
"Eugenio";"Martinez";45;"7,6,5"
"Marta";"Carrera";22;"1,6,2"
"Nacho";"Herrera";25;"3,4,2"
```